# Intersect JavaScript console.log() calls and send the data to my own logger function

Tags: javascript

How can I hijack calls to the browsers `console.log` and send them to my own log function while still letting them make there normal `console.log` entry.

Sites like JSBin and CodePen allow you to view there version of a console log in the page DOM while still making the console.log entry as well.

So every time I call `console.log('my log msg');` it should behave like normal but also pipe/send the console log data to my own JavaScript `logger.log('log entry')` function.

How can this be done?

---

### UPDATE

Desired custom logger output of an object:

Logging this object:

```
var data = {
  date: new Date(),
  prop2: 'sfgsdgsd',
  arrayProp: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'],
  arrayOfObjectsProp: [
  {
      date: new Date(),
      date2: new Date()
  },{
      date: new Date(),
      date2: new Date()
  },{
      date: new Date(),
      date2: new Date()
  }]      
};
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(data);
}, 10000);
```

In the Logger will show as:

```
{
  "date": "2017-01-01T03:19:46.944Z",
  "prop2": "sfgsdgsd",
  "arrayProp": [
    "key1",
    "key2",
    "key3"
  ],
  "arrayOfObjectsProp": [
    {
      "date": "2017-01-01T03:19:46.944Z",
      "date2": "2017-01-01T03:19:46.944Z"
    },
    {
      "date": "2017-01-01T03:19:46.944Z",
      "date2": "2017-01-01T03:19:46.944Z"
    },
    {
      "date": "2017-01-01T03:19:46.944Z",
      "date2": "2017-01-01T03:19:46.944Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all You must understand that `console.log` takes dynamic amount of arguments.

So You should not end Your job with: `console.log = function(text) {}`

You've to get magic variable `arguments` and then call original log function inside of custom function.

So see this example:

```js
console.log2 = console.log; // keeping original function under new name

console.log = function() {
  // converting arguments object to array
  var args = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0); 
   
  // calling original log function with args
  console.log2.apply(this, args); 

  // doing something else...      
  document.getElementById('debug-bar').innerHTML = 'Debug: '+ args.join(' ');
};

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(new Date());
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="debug-bar"></div>
```

P.S. if it's nodejs app so You can use `winston` package that is very flexible for customizations.

Comment: The console log DIV that the StackOverflow editor shows in your demo is actually what I am trying to achieve.  I want to make a really light weight drop in JS lib that adds a console logger DIV to the DOM that will pipe console.log calls to itand format and show objects and arrays and stuff like the console does.  Looking at the console in your demo from StackOverflow it handles objects and arrays and nested items just as I need.  I updated my question to show what I mean.  DO you know how to do a logger like that?

Comment: I just found there JS file http://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1 driopping it in as page makes it work anywhere!

Answer (score 8):

You could assign old `console.log` to a variable called, for instance, `oldlog`, and then assign to `console.log` your own function, which would do all the necessary things, and then call `oldlog` in the very end, passing given text as a parameter

```
var oldlog = console.log
console.log = function(...args) {
  // do something fancy with text passed
  oldlog(...args);
}
```

**EDIT**
As mentioned by KevBot, `console.log` can take unlimited number of arguments, so, to cover all the cases, your function should allow this behavior. This can be done using ES6 feature called [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) or, without relying on ES6, using `arguments` array-like object, as described in num8er's answer

Also, as mentioned by Oriol, some browsers wont allow `oldlog` to be called not on `console`. This can be fixed by changing the line

```
oldlog(...args)
```

in your custom `console.log` to

```
oldlog.call(console, ...args)
```

Comment: Don't forget that `console.log()` can receive `n` number of arguments.

Comment: Some browsers won't allow `oldlog` not to be called on a `console` object. You should use `call` or `apply`.

Comment: and in mozilla dev network website tells You that no need to wait for ES6 (:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments